# WPF radio button checking

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

Now im coding my first gui program and i have a problem(I know its very simple,but i cant find an answer for it).I have 2 radio buttons,separeted from eachother,and i cant check if radio button is checked ,here`s my code:

```
 <RadioButton Content="Metinės"
                 Checked="RadioButton_Checked_1"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="393,124,0,0"
                 Height="21"
                 Width="101"
                 FontSize="14"
                 ClickMode="Press"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold"/>
```

And c#

```
  if (RadioButton_Checked == true)
            {
                //program code
            }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Give `x:Name` or `Name` to your `RadioButton` like

```
<RadioButton x:Name="MyRadioButton" Content="Metinės"/>
```

and then in code behind you can check

```
if(MyRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find out like this

Give your Radio Button name using `x:Name ="RBMetLines"` and access that in code behind

```
<RadioButton Content="Metinės"
             x:Name="RBMetLines"
             Checked="RBMetLines_Checked"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="393,124,0,0"
             Height="21"
             Width="101"
             FontSize="14"
             ClickMode="Press"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold"/>
```

and in C# code behind

```
private void RBMetLines_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(Convert.ToBoolean(RBMetLines.IsChecked))
    {
        //program code
    }
}
```

I have converted IsChecked to Boolean because in WPF IsChecked is `bool?`.

Comment: You wouldn't have to explain your code if you'd written if(RBMetLines.HasValue && RBMetLines.Value) instead